# Symfony2: Add property to object in controller

Tags: symfony

What i wanna do: I have users in my db in in my controller i get them in $users. Those entity has an event-property, in it it stores the id of an event-object.

now in my controller i loop through the users of my $users object and get the event for every id of the current user. then i want to read the titel-property of this event and set it as another property of user, like user.eventtitle, so i can access this title in my twig-view.

understand? im shure there is a way to achieve this, but im not shure if mine is the best way.. :P

thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a proxy function in your user class

```
public function getEventTitle(){
    return $this->event->getTitle();
}
```

or get it in twig template

```
{{ user.event.title }}
```

write your own DQL query for finding users with event joined ( if you're using doctrine ) to get the event object in one query , and avoid lazy loading.

```
SELECT u, e FROM YourBundle:User u LEFT JOIN u.event WHERE u.id = :id
```

**EDIT :**

if you don't know how to get your associations working, read [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html).

Comment: wouldnt it be better to make a direct connection between my user and my event entity? how can i achieve that?

and, is it then possible to do something like user.event.title?

Comment: yes it is, i updated the answer with reference. you should read it, if you don't know how to make associations work. i'm using doctrine, so it's a doctrine doc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create another attribut to your User entity class with associated getter/setter

```
protected $eventTitle;

public function getEventTitle() {
    return $this->eventTitle;
}
```

You don't specify any persistence annotation.
Then you can populate this property through your controller loop.

Comment: wouldnt it be better to make a direct connection between my user and my event entity? how can i achieve that?

and, is it then possible to do something like user.event.title?

Comment: I thought you hadn't any event entity. Then what about create a one to many event property ? You will be able to perform an user.event.title call in twig if the event is not null (test with 'user.event is defined and user.event')